# Attempting to insert date string into SQL table with pandas dataframe.to_sql function, but it reformats the string

Tags: python, sql, pandas

The dataframe contains a varchar(10), which contains a date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', and I am inserting it into a varchar(10) column in a SQL table with pandas' to_sql method. The resulting table has the date formatted as 'MMM-DD-YYY' (abbreviated month name, truncated to 10 characters). Any ideas?

Comment: what's the dtype of the column?

Comment: How are you querying the table, still through pandas or something else?

Comment: both the dataframe column and the table column are varchar(10)

Comment: Through DataGrip

Comment: I would start by changing the column with  .to_datetime(yearfirst = True)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workable example, hard to test against your database of course :)

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(['2022-10-18', '2022-09-07'], columns = ['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], yearfirst = True).dt.date
df.to_sql('my_dates', con = engine, index = False)
engine.execute("SELECT  dates FROM my_dates").fetchall()
```